# Immutable setIn nested object returning invalid keyPath error

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I've got the following object:

```
const initialState = Map({
  posts: {
    most_popular: [],
    trending: [],
    latest: [],
  }
});
```

And I'm trying to update a sub object within entries. Here is what I've tried:

```
intialState.setIn(["posts", "most_popular"], ["array", "of", "values"]);
```

Running this set command will return

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid keyPath()
```

Am I missing something? I don't need to create sub maps do I? E.g

```
const initialState = Map({
      posts: Map({
        most_popular: [],
```

Obviously that doesn't work (*I've tried*), but maybe there is another way of setting sub object up?

EDIT:

Getting the object, and updating like so works:

```
state.get("entries").most_popular = ["k"];
```

But this means my entries.most_popular (trending, latest) aren't immutable? Is there a way to make sub objects immutable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Map()`, use `fromJS()`. If you use `Map()`, then the array under your key `most_popular` is a standard JS object, not an Immutable.js structure.

Thus:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  posts: {
    most_popular: [],
    trending: [],
    latest: [],
  }
});
```

Now everything is an Immutable object. Then you can easily do:

```
initialState.setIn(["posts", "most_popular"], ["array", "of", "values"]);
```